# Wordpress - Admin Manage Posts - Multiple Filters by Parent Category

Tags: wordpress

Lets say I have the following Categories in Wordpress:

Product Category
   - Cat A
   - Cat B
   - Cat C

Service Type
   - Service A
   - Service B
   - Service C

On the Manage Posts page on the Admin side, I want to have 2 drop down filters for both Product Category, and Service Type, so I can filter by both on the backend.

How can I do this?

Comment: you might try posting on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Is this what you need?
Dashboard > All Posts > View All Categories (at the top of page) > Filter

Comment: No, I want to have multiple filters on that page.  So the 'View All Categories' allows you to filter by 1 ctageory.  I want to have a filter for every Parent category, so I can filter by a few at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in the wordpress stackexchange: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53202/8706